# Ruby can not find gem amongst even though it is in the list

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant

I am having a strange issue where when I try and run `vagrant up` the system can suddenly not find the json gem.  When I run vagrant up I get this message:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find  json (~> 1.5.1) amongst [Platform-0.4.0, archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2, builder-3.0.0,  bundler-1.1.5, childprocess-0.3.5, cucumber-1.2.1, diff-lcs-1.1.3, erubis-2.7.0, ffi-1.1.5, gemcutter-0.7.1, gherkin-2.11.2, git-1.2.5, hiera-0.3.0, hiera-json-0.3.0, hiera-puppet-0.3.0, highline-1.6.13, i18n-0.6.0, json-1.7.5, log4r-1.1.10, metaclass-0.0.1, mocha-0.12.3, net-scp-1.0.4, net-ssh-2.5.2, open4-1.3.0, popen4-0.1.2, progressbar-0.11.0, puppet-module-0.3.4, puppetlabs_spec_helper-0.3.0, rake-0.9.2.2, rspec-2.11.0, rspec-core-2.11.1, rspec-expectations-2.11.2, rspec-mocks-2.11.2, rspec-puppet-0.1.4, thor-0.16.0, vagrant-1.0.3, veewee-0.2.3, virtualbox-0.9.2] (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:771:in `activate_dependencies'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:760:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:760:in `activate_dependencies'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:744:in `activate'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1209:in `gem'
        from /usr/local/bin/vagrant:18
```

As you can see from the error above the json gem is clearly in the list, yet it will not recognize it.  I have searched for this issue and found many occurrences but most of the time the gem is not present in the amongst list.  I do not have ruby installed multiple times and the gem path is set.

gem env

RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
- RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:

  - /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - /home/adrian/.gem/ruby/1.8
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :benchmark => false
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:

  - http://rubygems.org/

The installation directories are default on Ubuntu 12.04.

gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.5)
childprocess (0.3.5)
cucumber (1.2.1)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
ffi (1.1.5)
gemcutter (0.7.1)
gherkin (2.11.2)
git (1.2.5)
hiera (0.3.0)
hiera-json (0.3.0)
hiera-puppet (0.3.0)
highline (1.6.13)
i18n (0.6.0)
json (1.7.5)
log4r (1.1.10)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mocha (0.12.3)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-ssh (2.5.2)
open4 (1.3.0)
Platform (0.4.0)
popen4 (0.1.2)
progressbar (0.11.0)
puppet-module (0.3.4)
puppetlabs_spec_helper (0.3.0)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rspec (2.11.0)
rspec-core (2.11.1)
rspec-expectations (2.11.2)
rspec-mocks (2.11.2)
rspec-puppet (0.1.4)
thor (0.16.0)
vagrant (1.0.3)
veewee (0.2.3)
virtualbox (0.9.2)
```

As you can see the gem is in the installed list here to.  The environment variables `$GEM_HOME` and `$GEM_PATH` are not set.

I have been trying to figure this one out but am currently at a loss.  Any help from a Ruby and/or Vagrant expert would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you pointed here, you have already installed json gem version `1.7.5`. But the error message you are getting states `Could not find json (~> 1.5.1)`. The `~>` syntax means that only `1.5.x` versions are acceptable! So, you need to install one of these to satisfy the dependencies.